# table to table copy command with where condition

Tags: sql, vertica

Is there anyway to write a **copy command direct** which will copy data from 1 table and populate another table (with some condition will be better)?

what I have observed copy command performance is far more better that `INSERT INTO` in vertica. So I am trying to replace the `INSERT INTO` with copy command.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is an `INSERT /*+ DIRECT */ INTO table2 SELECT ... FROM table1 WHERE ...`.  The direct hint will make it do a direct load to ROS containers instead of through WOS.  If you are doing large bulk loads, this would be fastest. If you are doing many small insert/selects like this, then it would be best to use WOS and leave out the DIRECT.

Another possibility would be to do a `CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT ...  FROM table1 WHERE ...`.

Finally, if you are really just copying all the data and not filtering (which I know isn't your question, but I'm including this for completeness)... and the tables are partitioned, you can do a [`COPY_PARTITONS_TO_TABLE`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/COPY_PARTITIONS_TO_TABLE.htm) which will just create references from the source table's ROS containeres to the target table. Any changes to the new table would reorganize the ROS containers  (over time, using the tuple mover, etc.  Containers wouldn't get cleaned up unless both tables reorganized them).

Comment: Thanks @woot!!, I am using INSERT /*+DIRECT */ but its performance is not as good as copy command. Its taking longer time to load 1 million records.

Comment: @Biswabid Are you using a sequence? Are the projections segmented the same between the source and target table?

Comment: yes , I am having sequence in place. though I am not sure about the projections of source and target.

Comment: I just noticed you were the same person who asked the other question. Read my answer there, I think it'll help you.  To get the DDL for your projections, you can do `select export_objects('','schema.table');`  If your target table has a sequence itself and it is segmented on that, then it'll force it to resegment the data across the cluster.